# How can i get infomation of the subscription of a node

Tags: ros, exploration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have to write code to get the simulation of a robot that explores certains worlds with the stage simulator.
The point is that i want to get information of the laser scanner and i don't know how to do it...

I have the subscription...

```
 // Create a subscriber object 
 ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("/base_scan", 1000, processScanCallback);
```

where `processScanCallback` is:

```
void processScanCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    int n_ranges = msg->ranges.size();
    double nearest = *(std::min_element(msg->ranges.begin(),msg->ranges.end()));
        ROS_INFO_STREAM("I've a total of " << n_ranges << " measurements to process! Are you ready? Nearest="  nearest );
}
```

and i call `ros::SpinOnce();` inside a while-loop (where the robot is constantly doing measures and moving randomly), but those measurements are inside the function `processScanCallback` in the varible `nearest`. So, i have messages in the rosout node every time that the robot do a measure, but i can't do something with that value because is not returned...

How can i receive the value `nearest` from the `processScanCallback` function?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225933/how-can-i-get-infomation-of-the-subscription-of-a-node/) by [egr](https://answers.ros.org/users/25829/egr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-02-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) on 2016-02-08**:
Is it possible to change the processScanCallback signature ? (void processScanCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& msg, double& nearest) and you declare the variable "nearest" in your main)

**Comment by [egr](https://answers.ros.org/users/25829/egr/) on 2016-02-12**:
No, the only thing that i can do is declare `nearest` as a global variable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I declare `nearest` as a global variable and after that i can use this variable in the main function.

---

Originally posted by [egr](https://answers.ros.org/users/25829/egr/) with karma: 16 on 2016-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0